# Android peer to peer communication using 3g

Tags: android, 3g

I want to send some bits like small amount of data (so not text or file) using 3g data connection in the android phones. I don't want to use Wifi and I need some thing like a peer-to-peer connection or client server connection using only the android phones and its 3g/4g functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of your question has been answered in the past

[Detect network connection type on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

As for those small bits of data I suggest sending a udp packet every 30 seconds or so to prevent the ip from changing, as per the advice of this question answer.

[UDP port changes every time over 3G connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106010/udp-port-changes-every-time-over-3g-connection)